# Solutions in Bi-stable Regime

Tags: non-linear-optics

I am trying to plot the Bi-stable behavior governed by the equation:
[image]

Here the parameters have given numerical values.
For a certain range of $x$ there exists three roots. Ideally two of these should  be purely real and the other complex. I tried plotting it in Mathematica and from the graph it seems that for this range of $x$ only one root is purely real and and others are complex.

Now there are two possibilities:

1)Either there is something wrong with my program, graph etc (which I have checked multiple times by also explicitly calculating roots for this range), or;

2. My equation ***cannot give*** two purely real values in the range of $x$ where three roots exist and hence there is some fault in my derivation of the equation.

I do not know how to go about solving this conundrum. Any suggestions on how to deal with it are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a math question. Do you need to find $y$? In this case, you have an algebraic equation of third degree. Such equations *always* have three roots (some roots can be degenerate). If the coefficients of the equation are real, in general position, the equation has three real roots or one real and two complex roots, conjugated to each other. It is also possible for specially tuned parameters that the equation has two real roots, one being degenerate. The last possibility is that the equation has only one root of the third degree.

Comment: 'The last possibility is the equation has only one root of third degree'. It seems then that you cannot have a case with two purely real and one complex since complex roots come in conjugates. Is this correct?. The relation of this equation is to the bistability of  an optomechanical system   where y is the intra-cavity intensity. This system supports two stable intensities while third being unstable(imaginary or complex). My equation should have a graph supporting this but its not coming apparently. I think probably one of the real roots can also make it unstable.

Comment: @Lost Yes, you can not have two real and one complex roots if the equation has real coefficients.